# Asterisk on Password

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, accessibility, experience

why is enter password on asterisks ( first time )
and why not on confirm password (Second time)
Why is this method being followed mostly nowadays.
Mostly in banking app.

Does it makes sense actually.

User types password for first time and everything is in asterisks then confirm password is clearly visible,Shouldn't it be the reverse of it.
What is the psychology behind it ?

[image]

Comment: Can u include the link of the app where u find this kind of option? Coz, i have never seen password visible anywhere..

Comment: I also never seen this kind of scenario so please add some ref links.

Comment: Probably it's just a mistake in the implementation.

Comment: Not related to password but similar incident, I've noticed. In Indian bank's website/app(HDFC, ICICI) when you add a new beneficiary number, it ask for a/c number, which has the same interaction(design pattern) as raised by OP.

Comment: Those are the poor examples of UI/UX, this is what something that would help you: http://uxmovement.com/forms/why-the-confirm-password-field-must-die/